# Linking problem when building apriltag_ros package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to build this project (http://wiki.ros.org/apriltag_ros) in Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS-melodic.

I just did:

(i) cd catkin_ws/src/

(ii) git clone https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag_ros.git

(iii) cd catkin_ws/ & catkin_make

I'm getting a linking problem against a very basic ROS library:

```
[ 96%] Linking CXX executable /home/das/catkin_ws/devel/lib/apriltag_ros/apriltag_ros_single_image_client_node
CMakeFiles/apriltag_ros_single_image_client_node.dir/src/apriltag_ros_single_image_client_node.cpp.o: In function `main':
apriltag_ros_single_image_client_node.cpp:(.text.startup+0x101): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__debug::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
apriltag_ros_single_image_client_node.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b0): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__debug::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324462/linking-problem-when-building-apriltag_ros-package/) by [dasanche](https://answers.ros.org/users/20993/dasanche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-06-01**:
Please don't [crosspost](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag_ros/issues/48). It wastes the effort of people on both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by removing the .catkin_tools, .private, build, devel, logs directories in the root of the workspace manually.
Initializing again (catkin config --init )

---

Originally posted by [dasanche](https://answers.ros.org/users/20993/dasanche/) with karma: 83 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0